# Auto layout calculating same height for each collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

So I have a collection view that uses a custom layout that I found on Github called [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) I like it so far, however I am looking to make the custom collection view cell I made dynamic in height, and I am having trouble connecting Auto Layout to calculate this. I shared a simple sample project on Github that generates random string sizes and displays them, only problem is that Auto Layout generates the same cell height for each Collection View Cell. The project can be found [here](https://github.com/wyguy321/DynamicCollectionViewWithAutoLayout).

To give you a run down of my thought process, I calculate the cell height by using the method `CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout` sizeForItemAtIndexPath. Since I also use the delegates method `columnCountforSection` my thought is since I provide a finite number of columns based on the orientation, I take the collectionView frame width and I divide by the number of columns to get me my width for the cell.

[image]

```
   func collectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        var cell = dict["heightCell"] as? CollectionViewCell

        let randomString = RadomStrings[indexPath.item]

        let float = CGFloat(columnCount)
        let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width / float
        if cell == nil {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CollectionViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CollectionViewCell
            dict["heightCell"] = cell
        }
        cell?.RandomStringLabel.text = randomString
        cell!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell!.frame))
               cell!.setNeedsLayout()
             cell!.layoutIfNeeded()
        var size = cell?.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        size?.width = width
     return CGSize(width: width, height: size!.height)
    }
```

My constraints are pretty basic. I have a constraint on each axis. One on the top of the content view, leading, trailing and bottom. I also have a height on the label that is greater than or equal to 45.

Using Auto Layout to calculate TableViewCell heights is easy to me and I like it because I like the DRY principle behind this height calculation approach. So I would like to keep this height calculation process the same throughout my app. CollectionViews are a relatively new layout process for me, so I would love to learn what I am doing wrong here. Hopefully I am clear for everyone, thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: Hmm thanks for the reference! Back when I was first getting to learn how self sizing cells worked, I referenced that page a bunch for UITableView. I'll put on some focusing music and hopefully I can figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! What I didn't do is put a width constraint on the custom cell I created! Duh!